# EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java, zip

I am facing this issue while unzipping a file and writing it in to another file. Here is the code. Can any one please let me know what changes are required.

I get this exception on the line with `while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0)`

```
private FileItem readZippedFileRequest(HttpServletRequest request,Part part, String fileName) {

    FileItem fileItem = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);

    ZipEntry entry;    
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream fos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int len;
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        InputStream myByteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(fos.toByteArray());
        fileItem = createCSVFile(myByteArray, fileName,ImportExportConstant.FILE_TYPE_EXCEL);
    }       

    return fileItem;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. There is something wrong with the file, as the message says. Are you sure it is zipped, and not GZipped for example? It would be more usual for a part to be GZipped. Try a `GZIPInputStream.`

NB there's no need for the `ByteArrayInputStream.` It's a complete waste of time and space. Just pass the zip/gzip input stream directly to your `createCSVFile()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too and I searched a little bit... I've read that there must be `zis.closeEntry();` before `len = zis.read(buffer)` but I tried it and then the error appears at `zis.closeEntry();`
I asked google and here is the answer:

!Answer!

I tried and wrote a little bit, then I switched the `throws IOException` in a `try/catch-block` and now there is all right. 
The Exception is a well known bug. You have to put all in a `try/catch-block` and do nothing in the catch.

```
private FileItem readZippedFileRequest(HttpServletRequest request,Part part, String fileName) {

    FileItem fileItem = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);

        ZipEntry entry;    
        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            ByteArrayOutputStream fos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            InputStream myByteArray = new   ByteArrayInputStream(fos.toByteArray());
            fileItem = createCSVFile(myByteArray, fileName,ImportExportConstant.FILE_TYPE_EXCEL);
        }       
    }catch(IOException ex){
        //Do nothing here
    }
    return fileItem;
}
```